# What’s the best way to achieve this several options/quantities pricing model? (not tier)

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, quantity

We sell tours and activities, and often price for child is different from adult price.

Currently to achieve needed functionality we are creating 2 simple products for each product (productX-adult, productX-child) and put them in main bundle product (productX)

I am wondering is there a better way to do it?

We will need to add Senior option to some products in near future, so it will be 3 QTY selectors and each will have different price.

So with our current set-up we will have to create 3 simple products(productY-adult, productY-child, productY-senior) and 1 main bundle(productY) for each product.

What’s the better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each ticket is and individual entity. By this I mean that age is not an attribute on product which can be grouped, it is more like a shape of an object. If something is a sphere then it is not a cube. Same for an age in this case. Therefore, if someone add one adult and one senior ticket he will add 2 different products. And the logic is as you described.

There is no better out of the box approach because age in this case is actually a type of product.

It could be done with custom options, rules, tier prices or simillar approach but not when you want to have a separate qty for each type. Attributes, options - all of these are related to a particular product. When you need different qty for different type you should use bundle product as you did.

Comment: Thank you,  your reply was very helpful. 

I did not like that we have to create separate simple product for each option (adult, child, senior), i wondered if there is a way to keep them within 1 product. 

But i see now that it's logical and right magento way to do it.